# Room database get Set of type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, androidx

I need to get `set` of strings from `RoomDatabase`

Entity:

```
@Entity
data class Data(
@PrimaryKey val id: Int,
val type: String,
val photo: String
)
```

I need to get `set` of types. I've try follow method:

```
...
@Query("SELECT type FROM data")
fun getAllTypes(): LiveData<Set<String>>
...
```

Now I has next error:

```
C:\...\storage\DataDao.java:24: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>).
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.Set<java.lang.String>> getAllTypes();
[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get Set, sorry. According to documentation for SELECT queries you can use only List or Array.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query

If you need to have unique items you can use SQL's DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
@Query("SELECT type FROM data")
```

Must be this:

```
@Query("SELECT type FROM Data")
```